# Private method error while overriding Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository

Tags: magento-2.1, overrides, resource-model, preference

I am using `<preference>` to override CustomerRepository, but
`Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository` contains private functions and it throws me error

```
Fatal error: Call to private method Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository::populateCustomerModelWithSecureData() from context 'Custom\Mod\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository' in /var/www/html/WC/M2/store/app/code/Custom/Mod/Model/ResourceModel/CustomerRepository.php on line 60
```

I want to completely override the `save()` function, and add many more functions. The private functions doesn't allow me to do so. It shouldn't require me to define the private functions again due to strict versional maintenance. Any solution for this?

The custom `di.xml` has this

```
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository"
                type="Custom\Mod\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository" />
```

The customized CustomerRepository is

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Custom\Mod\Model\ResourceModel;

/**
 * Customer repository.
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class CustomerRepository extends \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository
{


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function save(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer, $passwordHash = null) {
        $prevCustomerData = null;
        $prevCustomerDataArr = null;

        if ($customer->getId()) {
            $prevCustomerData = $this->getById($customer->getId());
            $prevCustomerDataArr = $prevCustomerData->__toArray();
        }

        /** @var $customer \Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer */
        $customerArr = $customer->__toArray();
        $customer = $this->imageProcessor->save(
                $customer, \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $prevCustomerData
        );

        $origAddresses = $customer->getAddresses();

        $customer->setAddresses([]);
        $customerData = $this->extensibleDataObjectConverter->toNestedArray(
                $customer, [], \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface::class
        );

        $customer->setAddresses($origAddresses);
        $customerModel = $this->customerFactory->create(['data' => $customerData]);
        $storeId = $customerModel->getStoreId();

        if ($storeId === null) {
            $customerModel->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        }

        $customerModel->setId($customer->getId());

        // Need to use attribute set or future updates can cause data loss
        if (!$customerModel->getAttributeSetId()) {
            $customerModel->setAttributeSetId(
                    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER
            );
        }
        // Populate model with secure data
        $this->populateCustomerModelWithSecureData($customer, $passwordHash, $customerModel);

        // If customer email was changed, reset RpToken info
        if ($prevCustomerData && $prevCustomerData->getEmail() !== $customerModel->getEmail()
        ) {
            $customerModel->setRpToken(null);
            $customerModel->setRpTokenCreatedAt(null);
        }


        $this->setDefaultBilling($customerArr, $prevCustomerDataArr, $customerModel);

        $this->setDefaultShipping($customerArr, $prevCustomerDataArr, $customerModel);

        $bo=0;
        if(isset($customerArr['custom_attributes']['back_office']['value'])){
            if($customerArr['custom_attributes']['back_office']['value']==1)
                $bo=1;
        }
        if($customerArr['custom_attributes']['customer_type']['value']=='abal'||$bo==1){

               if($customerArr['custom_attributes']['customer_type']['value']=='abal'){
                   $customerModel->setGroupId(4);
               }

                    $customerModel->save();

                    $this->customerRegistry->push($customerModel);

                    $customerId = $customerModel->getId();
                    $this->updateAddresses($customer, $customerId);
                    if($bo=1){
                    $this->updateft($customer);
                    }
                    if(isset($customerArr['id'])&&$customerArr['custom_attributes']['customer_type']['value']=='abal'){
                        $this->insertcustdetails($customer,$customerId);
                    }
                    $savedCustomer = $this->get($customer->getEmail(), $customer->getWebsiteId());
                    $this->eventManager->dispatch(
                            'customer_save_after_data_object', ['customer_data_object' => $savedCustomer, 'orig_customer_data_object' => $customer]
                    );

                    return $savedCustomer;

        }
        else{

        $resp = NULL;
        if (!isset($customerArr['id'])) {

                $customerArr = $customer->__toArray();

                $resp = $this->curlCall($customerArr);
                if ($resp == "registration_successfull") {
                    $customerModel->save();
                    $this->customerRegistry->push($customerModel);
                    $customerId = $customerModel->getId();

                    $this->updateAddresses($customer, $customerId);

                    $savedCustomer = $this->get($customer->getEmail(), $customer->getWebsiteId());
                    $this->eventManager->dispatch(
                            'customer_save_after_data_object', ['customer_data_object' => $savedCustomer, 'orig_customer_data_object' => $customer]
                    );
                    return $savedCustomer;
                } else {

                    try{
                        $number = 5/0;
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t save the customer.'));
                    }


                }

        }
        else{

            $customerModel->save();
                    $this->customerRegistry->push($customerModel);
                    $customerId = $customerModel->getId();
                    $this->updateft($customer);
                    $this->updateaddress($customer);
                    $this->updateAddresses($customer, $customerId);

                    $savedCustomer = $this->get($customer->getEmail(), $customer->getWebsiteId());
                    $this->eventManager->dispatch(
                            'customer_save_after_data_object', ['customer_data_object' => $savedCustomer, 'orig_customer_data_object' => $customer]
                    );
                    return $savedCustomer;

        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to edit in save() function just use only save() in your file

Comment: I have added the code, since private functions cannot be extended, it throws me error.

Comment: Remove Private functions your module file, just try using save() function. Or post the code here.

Comment: I do not have private functions in my module, but i require calling them. Is there any way except defining the private functions again?

Answer (score 1):

=> In **di.xml** of your custom module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository" 
    type="Custom\Mod\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository" />
</config>
```

=> In **CustomerRepository.php** File You have missed below function

```
/**
     * Set secure data to customer model
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customerModel
     * @param string|null $passwordHash
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @return void
     */
    private function populateCustomerWithSecureData($customerModel, $passwordHash = null)
    {
        if ($customerModel->getId()) {
            $customerSecure = $this->customerRegistry->retrieveSecureData($customerModel->getId());

            $customerModel->setRpToken($passwordHash ? null : $customerSecure->getRpToken());
            $customerModel->setRpTokenCreatedAt($passwordHash ? null : $customerSecure->getRpTokenCreatedAt());
            $customerModel->setPasswordHash($passwordHash ?: $customerSecure->getPasswordHash());

            $customerModel->setFailuresNum($customerSecure->getFailuresNum());
            $customerModel->setFirstFailure($customerSecure->getFirstFailure());
            $customerModel->setLockExpires($customerSecure->getLockExpires());
        } elseif ($passwordHash) {
            $customerModel->setPasswordHash($passwordHash);
        }

        if ($passwordHash && $customerModel->getId()) {
            $this->customerRegistry->remove($customerModel->getId());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I did this, my problem is after doing this step, i have mentioned it in the question.

Comment: Can you Post the code in the question @Midlaj

Comment: i have added the code

Comment: Please find the above code That You have missed @Midlaj

Comment: Yes, i understand i do not have that code since a private function cannot be extended. But is there any way to override without defining the private functions again, this is because future version changes shouldn't require anyone else to redefine the private functions again.

Comment: When You trying to override the vendor file while you can add the function it will indeed useses but in case it is not called,you can put private method @Midlaj

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75179/discussion-between-midlaj-and-pranay-k).

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this in order to extend feature this might help you :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomClassName" />
</config>
```

Make sure your model code look like this :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository;

Class CustomClassName extends CustomerRepository
{
   ...................
   ...................
   ...................
}
```

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't go to my customized CustomerRepository. It goes to core customer module's customerrepository

Comment: check above modification , match with your code @midlaj

Comment: i tried the same, it goes to core customer module itself, not my customclaass

Comment: You need to run following command :
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento c:f

Comment: Yeah, i have run that